# Rear light on vintage motorcycle 6 V split to 5 V

Tags: voltage

I have a 6 volt vintage motorcycle. With it being a 1920s motorbike, there was no need for a brake light to be attached/fitted by law just a rear light. However I am not comfortable with this and I put my arm out and swing it around to warn people that I'm slowing down. But people still get annoyed and flip fingers and some want to fight me, because nobody knows nowadays what hand signals are.

The problem I have is I don't want to destroy the appearance and remove the old light or fit light boards etc. I want to keep it aesthetically pleasing for the rivet counters.

The light currently fitted is a 6 V single-element bulb and no way of fitting a dual-element due to the size of the fittings.

I was thinking of doing the standard rear brake switch earth etc, but then if I had to put the rear light on for some reason, then the brake light would not glow brighter.

My electrical engineering is pretty poor I'm afraid. My question is: Can I have one live wire going to the light and say lower the voltage by say 1 or 2 V, yes dim but viable? And then 6 V by the brake switch earth, so it glows brighter when pressed. However how would I stop it feeding full power and stop it bleeding the circuits together etc? Is there a piece of kit that will split the live wires? I could then hide the box under the seat, as long as it's not too big.

Comment: A lot of stuff from the 20s is relatively easily disassemblable and often spacious.  You might want to consider whether you can rewire the holder with LEDs.  You've probably seen modern police ghost cars for an example of just how much extra lighting you can hide in standard fixture sizes.  It's a lot more complicated, but hard to beat the results with old school bulbs.  You've mentioned you don't want to fit light boards, but if your only reason is aesthetics, I wouldn't rule that out.

Answer (score 1):

Just fit an easily removed [deceleration lamp](https://vtrcorp.com/) and save all the faffing about: -

> **Our rear-end collision avoidance system is simple yet effective. After
> you install our deceleration light on the back of your truck or
> trailer, it will light up and flash when you start to slow or brake.**

Here's one from Shamazon: -

[image]

And here's [another one](http://www.mechoptix.com/stoptix-auto) that can be fitted to motorbikes: -

[image]

> *The problem I have I don't want to destroy the appearance and remove
> the old light or fit light boards etc and want to keep it
> aesthetically pleasing for the rivet counters.*

You can even get ones that [fit to helmets](https://www.pinterest.co.uk/pin/465137467751841304/) thus pleasing the rivet counters (if they could ever be pleased!): -

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that but unfortunately that one  wont work the bulb itself is too large to fit ,the bulb in the rear light on the bike is small and  fits in a tube no wider then 2" the bulb fitted is ba15s bulb 6v.

Comment: @SpuntBilly you don't fit it in the rear light. You add it as an easily removed extra piece of apparatus either to your helmet or to a convenient point on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

A setup like this should work. Values may vary for your specific bulb.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fW3icK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Dimming filament bulbs with resistors is a little tricky since the perceived brightness is not directly proportional to the voltage applied to the bulb. As a comparison, I made some measurements on a 12V8W bulb I had lying around (I don't have any 6V bulbs handy). V = Measured Voltage, A = Measured Current, W = Calculated Wattage, R = Calculated Filament Resistance, B = Measured Brightness with an ambient light sensor.
[image]

Comment: Great thank you , is there anyway it could be wired up without running a live to the brake switch. Can you also tell me what resistor I need as I've had a look on evil bay and just got confused with 1w 2w metal film etc. Sorry for being a noob.

Comment: An inertial switch would be about the only way to do that. Try looking at something like the STS Smart Brake Module.

Comment: How many watts is the light? That is what you need to determine the wattage of the resistor. Once you know the bulb wattage, you can calculate the resistor wattage. This gets a little tricky because the bulbs resistance changes as the current (filament temperature) changes.

Comment: I have had a look at its a 3w bulb if that helps .

Comment: One more little detail... You may need to change the bulb to get a good brake light. A tail light is typically around 40 lumen where a typical brake light is around 10 times that bright. Since you can't install a dual filament bulb, you may want to find a higher wattage (Greater Lumen) bulb so you can still have the tail light mode be decently visible. Doing this would change the resistor required.

Comment: I'm guessing the 6V3W G3-1/2 Mini Bayonet?

Comment: Yes that's the blub I'm not sure how to work at what resistor I need ?

Comment: My guestimate would be a 3.9 Ohm 5 Watt resistor for the bulb you have, but I don't think the results are going to be great with that bulb. You could go with a 767 which is an aircraft cabin bulb of 12W which would give you a nice bright brake light, but this means a much larger wattage on the resistor and maybe a heat sink. It all starts getting very much more complicated from there.

Comment: I have found a ba15s 6v 10w in my box would that be better , I'm only working off a dynamo and it's a super small battery 4.5 A.H  .

Comment: I think that would offer better brightness but it seems like wasting power is undesirable. You will likely need a 1 Ohm 25W resistor which is going to waste a lot of power. You may want to look around for LED replacements. You will likely need to have a microcontroller anyway if you don't want to run a wire from your brake switch. The microcontroller will allow efficient PWM brightness control of the LED.